# how do I animate a geneva drive with animation nodes?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I did this geneva drive but I don't know how to animate it
[image]

Simply dividing by 6 don't work because the second gear should only moves at a certain time. I already tried some equations but none of them worked.

The file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApEztyCWw8odpHHmdlx7qbN6Rf9v

edit: It is going to be part of a big gear system, so the second gear's rotation cannot reset, it needs to increase continuously.

Comment: Here you have the curves for the rotation function and below that the equations: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chronogrammes_croix_malte_4_branches_complet.svg

Comment: Suggestion: how about uploading Blend file? With your objects, somebody will have an answer for you.

Comment: I tried using the wikipedia function but it didn't work.

Comment: This geneva drive reminds me of a Youtuber called Thang01046. He is highly prolific with his videos on mechanical engineering. On average, he puts out one or two works a day.  https://www.youtube.com/user/thang010146

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here my solution:

[image]

1. First, I use modulo to get 360-rotation cycle.
2. Next I divide degrees to get 0-1 range.
3. When I use Curve interpolation to mach each cycle with rotation of secondary object. (Curve is drawn by hand)
4. Finally, get back to degrees with some scale (6 times smaller)

[image]

Note, that i'm don't care about real 360-degree rotation of secondary shape. It rotates in 0-60 degree range. If you want to get real rotation, you need to add each cycle to the result.

UPD:

> It works for this example where there is only those two gears, but not
>   for what I need because it will control a whole clock gear system, so
>   the second gear can't have its rotation being reseted

As I noted, If you want to get real rotation, you need to add each cycle to the result:

[image]

To get cycle number you need to divide rotation by 360, and convert result to integer using Floor function. When just multiply it by same number, -60 and add it to rotation

Comment: It works for this example where there is only those two gears, but not for what I need because it will control a whole clock gear system, so the second gear can't have its rotation being reseted.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a way to do it.

First of all you create a reference object where you are going to add a Fcurve. It can be a bone or an empty.

Then insert keyframes in the rotation of one of the axes. It will probably create keyframes in all axes, so just delete 2 of them.

After you need to insert keyframes in the frames -5,35 and 55 with the last with -60° value and then add a cycles modifies.

You will get something like this:
[image: image after all process]

In the end you just need to make this setup here:
[image: node setup]

If you want to make it and the gear has more or less steps, you just need to change the Fcurve scale.